# Unable to run spring boot 3.0.3 mojo error on run spring-boot-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Upgraded a Spring boot 2.7 project to 3.0.3 (current latest). When I'm trying to start it with `mvn -e -X spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local`. Then I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.3:run (default-cli) on project my-project: Process terminated with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.3:run (default-cli) on project my-project: Process terminated with exit code: 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Process terminated with exit code: 1
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.JavaProcessExecutor.run (JavaProcessExecutor.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.run (RunMojo.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:218)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Here are the relevant pom.xml parts:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.3</version>

  <name>my-project</name>



    <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <spring-boot.version>${project.parent.version}</spring-boot.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2.2.6.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    <springdoc.version>2.0.2</springdoc.version>
    <spring-security.version>6.0.2</spring-security.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</mapstruct.version>
    <awssdk.version>2.20.15</awssdk.version>

    ...
  </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2022.0.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
        <version>${awssdk.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- SQS listeners -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
          <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
      <version>${awssdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- API security -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
         <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-common</artifactId>
      <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
      <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ....
  </dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
              <version>0.2.0</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked,deprecation</compilerArgument>
          <compilerArgs>
            <compilerArg>
              -Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true
            </compilerArg>
            <compilerArg>
              -Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorVersionInfoComment=true
            </compilerArg>
            <compilerArg>
              -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
            </compilerArg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.resources.plugin}</version>
        <configuration>
          <delimiters>
            <delimiter>@</delimiter>
          </delimiters>
          <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

What am I missing? There are no more error messages (at least I can't produce them), and it was working fine with the earlier version of spring.

Comment: Exit code 1 means: (spring boot app) failed to start! (Try to get more logs)...upgrading from 2.7 to 3 is not trivial!! Please follow [upgrade guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/upgrading.html#upgrading).

Comment: "Since this is a major release of Spring Boot, upgrading existing applications can be a little more involved that usual..." from [3.0 release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes)

Comment: How about `mvn clean install`? (Or `package`;)

Comment: Did all lof the above things. Went through the upgrade guide. Mvn clean and package works. I just can't run the application.

Comment: Also: "IMPORTANT:For spring-boot v3 support, make sure you use [springdoc-openapi v2](https://springdoc.org/v2)" ..from [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/)

Comment: Didn't work sadly, upgraded springdocs to 2.0.2. This part would have caused issues too I guess, so thank you anyway!

Comment: Remove the properties you are using to define of spring-boot dependencies. Let the parent define them... that's the idea of using the parent... things like spring-security etc. also check the release notes of Spring Boot... what has changed in 3.X